# Constant core data updates in Today extension

Tags: ios, core-data, widget, swift3, today-extension

**

I am developing an instant messaging app and the chats (and other entities) are being stored in core data.
Recently I have added a *today extension* and updated my store to be shared in the app group.
All works well and whenever a chat is updated and stored to core data (while the app is running), I can see the changes reflected in the extension if I restart it (scroll away to the home screen and back to the extensions).

#### Now... to the problem

I have tried setting up a **FetchResultsController** in my *TodayViewController* to get notified upon updates. I have also tried adding a notification listener to **NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification**. None of it works while the extension is visible. GRRRRRR.....@!!@£!£@

We're probably not using the same implementation but I have seen the requested behaviour in Whatsapp's today extension. 
When tested, I have noticed that if the app is running in the background, it updated the view with a nice animation. If the app is completely closed, the entire content of the extension disappears (not what I would expect, but hey, they respond to a change even when the app is completely terminated).
It could be that their update is not driven by core data changes (which will help me in some way because I would be able to stop banging my head against the wall) but if so, how would they go about implementing such a thing? I wonder...

I am not trying to write to core data from the extension, just read realtime content.

**Some info**
The app is targeted for iOS 9.x+, written in swift 3.0 and is driving me mad sometimes.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Don't hesitate to respond.

P.S.
My console prints a "No active animation block!" message everytime the extension loads up. Any idea why?

**